# Implement a function on scheme (racket) that returns all possible subsets of a given set

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Sorry for the English.
Hello everyone, there is a problem of creating a function in scheme language, which returns all possible subsets of the set, including zero set.
The input function accepts a list, for example:

```
(sets-of-set ' (a b))
```

which returns (nil is an empty set)

```
(nil (a) (b) (a b)))
```

I tried to find a solution on the Internet, but it ended in failure. Also watched a couple of tutorials

> The Scheme Programming Language
>
> Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs

In them, too, answer not found. So please tell me how to implement this feature or best of all, what should the final code look like.

Comment: [What's in a powerset? A set's subsets...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622945/how-to-do-a-powerset-in-drracket/20623487#20623487)

Comment: @WillNess Yes, set's subsets

Comment: click on it... :)